# Multiple windows users, share the same Workspace in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

Is possible to create a workspace in eclipse that can be control by one or more users with the perating system Windows?

In this case i have two users (UserA and UserB) with 2 different sessions on windows. The UserA have in his workspace a project that i need to control, just like the servers.

Comment: Saros maybe? its not bad

Comment: I this case i have jboss install in the machine but i need to run jboss independently of the users. Can i do that with **Saros**?

Comment: I saw the program Saros but I do not want to have to get due to the same Workspace for two users

Answer (score 0):

there's a simpler way use home sharing system that's windows provide for free

i think it's simple like opening windows explorer

Comment: It is impossible to do it that way.